# Volume of body given with inequalities

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I need to find volume of body given with this: (using spheric coordinates)

$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq4$

$\frac{\sqrt3}{3}z\leq-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I know that first inequality is inside of the sphere. But I'm not sure about second. I think it is elipse.
I would appreciate picture and solution. I'm stuck with this for days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that: $$z^2\sin^2 \alpha=(x^2+y^2)\cos^2\alpha$$ shows a cone where $\alpha$ is a constant such that $0\leq\alpha\leq\pi$. Here, we see that $\alpha=\pi/6$. So, we have $$V=4\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/6}\int_{\rho=0}^2~\rho^2\sin\phi~d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

[image]

Comment: great! thank you =D i somehow got it myself but graphic is great

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\color{#ff0000}{\Large V}
&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}z\,\Theta\left(4 - x^{2} - y^{2} - z^{2}\right)
\Theta\left(-\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}\,} - {\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,z\right)
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm d}r\,r^{2}
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,\sin\left(\theta\right)
\Theta\left(4 - r^{2}\right)
\Theta\left(-r\,\sin\left(\theta\right)
            -
            {\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,r\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\\[3mm]&=
2\pi\int_{0}^{2}{\rm d}r\,r^{2}
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,\sin\left(\theta\right)\,
\Theta\left(-\sin\left(\theta\right)
            -
            {\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\\[3mm]&=
{16 \over 3}\,\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,\sin\left(\theta\right)\,
\Theta\left(-\sin\left(\theta\right)
            -
            {\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\\[3mm]&=
{16 \over 3}\,\pi\,\left\{%
\left.
-\cos\left(\theta\right)\,
\Theta\left(-\sin\left(\theta\right)
-
{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\right\vert_{0}^{\pi}\right.
\\[3mm]&\phantom{= {16 \over 3}\left[\,\,\right]}+
\\[3mm]&\phantom{= {16 \over 3}\left[\,\,\right]}
\left.
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,\cos\left(\theta\right)
\delta\left(-\sin\left(\theta\right)
-
{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\left[%
-\cos\left(\theta\right)
+
{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\sin\left(\theta\right)
\right]
\right\}
\\[3mm]&=
{16 \over 3}\,\pi\left[%
1
+
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,\cos\left(\theta\right)
\delta\left(\theta - {5\pi \over 6}\right)
{\rm sgn}\left(-\cos\left(\theta\right)
+
{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)
\right]
\\[3mm]&=
{16 \over 3}\,\pi\left[%
1
+
\cos\left(5\pi \over 6\right)
{\rm sgn}\left(-\cos\left(5\pi \over 6\right)
+
{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,\sin\left(5\pi \over 6\right)\right)
\right]
\\[3mm]&=
{16 \over 3}\,\pi\left\{%
1
+
\left(-\,{1 \over 2}\right)
{\rm sgn}\left(-\left[-\,{1 \over 2}\right]
+
{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,{1 \over 2}\right)
\right\}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\Large{8\pi \over 3}}
\end{align}